# Xamarin Forms Icons turn to I think Chinese characters for some reason

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

When I run the Xamarin Forms application on Android device, initially the icons are normal, and then when you click on the icon, it seems to re-render and changes to what I think is Chinese characters?

There is a bit of code in the Android project wherein it inherits from ViewRenderer where the native view is an ExpandableListView Android Widget.

The code uses Material Font Code https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/iconfont/codepoints from what I can tell.

For example, this string "\ue88a" initially shows as a Home icon then it changes to what is shown in the image.

I have been stuck on this all day, hence creating this post on here.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the system language settings of your device?

Comment: Just checked this and the Language on the device is English

Comment: Try changing it to english from another country. Check [this issue](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/360) from github.

Comment: I've tried changing to English for other countries but still the same thing.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez it looks like that is a known bug and is still open, so thank you for finding that for me.

Comment: You may still improve your question to see if there's something wrong or missing in the code.